# How to fetch json data from external url and compile list of objects using a handlebars template, then render it in bootstrap list?

Tags: javascript, html, json, handlebars.js

I am trying to load some JSON data from this external URL http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users

I really can't figure this out. I'm trying out Handlebars.js, but it doesn't display anything in my template except the bootstrap list I've created. Here's what I've got:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.6/handlebars.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<script>
  $.ajax({
  url: 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users',
  dataType:'json'
  success: function(names){
    var source = $('#tpl').html();
    var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
    var context = names;

    $('#container').html(template(context));
  }
    });
    </script>
<div id="users"></div>
<script id="tpl" type="text/template">
    <ul>
        {{#each name}} 
          <li>{{this}}</li>
        {{/each}} 
    </ul>
  </script>
<div class="container">
  <ul class="list-group">
<li class="list-group-item">Leanne Graham</li>
<li class="list-group-item">Ervin Howell</li>
<li class="list-group-item">Clementine Bauch</li>
<li class="list-group-item">Patricia Lebsack</li>
<li class="list-group-item">Chelsey Dietrich</li>
<li class="list-group-item">Mrs. Dennis Schulist</li>
<li class="list-group-item">Kurtis Weissnat</li>
<li class="list-group-item">Nicholas Runolfsdottir V</li>
<li class="list-group-item">Glenna Reichert</li>
<li class="list-group-item">Clementina DuBuque</li>
  </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated:(

Answer (score 1):

There are a few misused of Handlebar in your code:

1. The `$('#container')` should be `$('.container')`
2. `type="text/template"` should be `type="text/x-handlebars-template"`
3. Based on the data structure of the return json, it should be `{{#each this}}`, and then display `<li>{{name}}</li>`

So in summary, the correct code should be:

```
<script>
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users',
    dataType:'json',
    success: function(names){
      var source = $('#tpl').html();
      var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
      var context = names;
      $('.container').html(template(context));
    }
  });
</script>

<div id="users"></div>

<script id="tpl" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <ul>
    {{#each this}}
      <li>{{name}}</li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</script>
```